# How to preserve JButton background style when changing color?

Tags: java, swing, button

I like the default JButton look.
I have several buttons and I want to easily differentiate one of them.

I would like to preserve the rest of buttons as they are, but change the background color of the one. I know there is `setBackgroundColor` method, but this will erase this nice gradient, and this looks awkward (one button is flat and does not fit to the rest).

Is there a way to do this without having this gradient as image?
I would like them to look similar on different platforms.

I'm also open to other ways to differentiate button, if they don't change it's natural look (I know I can change font, but I would like to do it on the background - I feel it would look better).

Comment: It's very LAF dependent. For example, in Nimbus it's not possible.

Comment: Possible workaround: JToggleButton that always stays 'selected'. When you click it, make it selected again in the handler.